# How to read AT commands that Ubuntu sends to my 3G modem?

Tags: networking, usb-modem, 3g

The modem, Huawei E173 (12d1:1436) works out of the box with Ubuntu. I can connect to the Internet with no difficulties. I would like to know how Ubuntu does this. When connected, the modem is initialized with AT commands. Does network-manager or modem-manager keep these commands somewhere in a file? Is it possible to intercept and read them as they are sent?

Comment: Have a look at `wvdial` Found a link with your model: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DialupModemHowto/Huawei/E220 old but will still work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use wireshark to capture/filter/read USB data: [USB capture setup](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB)